# new SFP network for newbies

Tags: network, fiber, sfp

I never really sealed with SFP before but I want to created a new fibre network.

Can SFP just be plug & play like ethernet or do you need a lot of knowledge ? I assume it's carry the normal IP/Mac information?

I'm having a gigabit internet from a ONT (which from what I understand and unless I'm wrong can't be bypassed),

I was thinking about two configuration:

Replace my Synology Router with a EdgeRouter 4 or 6 with SFP and connect a optical cable from it to a new UniFi 8-150 switch, then connect a another UniFi 8-150 switch with the first one still using SFP.
 Keep my modem,  and get 3 UniFi 8-150 SFP (or what ever smallest model which handle SFP) and connect them together 
Does that make sense and do I need any more hardware?

Also, would cable like :9/125 OS2 - SC/APC-SC/APC Simplex Citronier"  50 m be the correct cable ?

PS I'm talking about UniFi but I'm open to any brand, just try to check if my setup would make sense.

[image: Cable]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SFP is a standard for modular network ports. Essentially, the empty SFP slot is "PHY-less" until you plug in a module - with an Ethernet SFP port, you can plug in a 1000BASE-T module for twisted pair, 1000BASE-SX for multi-mode fiber (550 m max.),  1000BASE-LX or single-mode fiber (10 km max.), or various others.

Fiber comes in two basic types: multi-mode/MMF (short reach) and single-mode/SMF (long reach). MMF comes in different grades (OM1-OM5), usually it's reasonable to go with OM4/OM5, everything else is largely obsolete or reduces the reach. Single-mode connectors come with PC/SPC/UPC or APC end faces - these must always match the jack.

The depicted cable is SMF (yellow) with APC connectors (green). The connector size is *SC*, SFPs generally use the smaller *LC* connectors.

Although fiber is usually described as "better", it actually doesn't matter too much if you use twisted pair or fiber. Fiber has far greater reach and is practically immune to electromagnetic interference, but it also is more expensive to deploy and terminate.

If you go with fiber and SFPs, do check whether an SFP module is compatible with your switch/router before buying. Most vendors lock their devices to use only "original" modules that very often come at a premium. There's a large 3rd-party market where you can get compatible modules for a fraction of the original vendor's price.

An important detail for fiber is *keep your connectors clean*. Even a  little dust can significantly degrade the signal and easily damage the end faces - on the patch cables as well as on the (possibly expensive) SFPs and panel jacks. Keep dust caps on all unused connectors at all times. Clean before inserting a connector. Keep unused dust caps in a closed bag.